# TypeError: Member "add" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in struct Chainlink.Request memory

Tags: ganache, truffle-migration, chainlink

I encounter this error when trying to compile and migrate to my blockchain EVM.The smart contract supposed to trigger a job from Chainlink from Ganache EVM. This is the code to it

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol";

contract FastAPI is ChainlinkClient {
    // Chainlink variables
    address private oracle;
    bytes32 private jobId;

    // Event to capture the API response
    event APIResponse(uint256 result);

    // Constructor
    constructor() {
        setPublicChainlinkToken();
        // Set the oracle address and Job ID for your specific Chainlink job
        oracle = 0x12F2d6b0783127C62956FfF73F4D7f701433b6f5; // Replace with the actual oracle address
        jobId = "2"; // Replace with the actual Job ID
    }

    // Function to request data from Chainlink external adapter
    function requestDataFromChainlink(string memory apiURL) public {
        Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(
            jobId,
            address(this),
            this.fulfill.selector
        );
        req.add("get", apiURL);
        req.add("path", "result"); // Path to the result in the API response JSON
        sendChainlinkRequestTo(oracle, req, 0); // Setting fee to 0 for Development mode
    }

    // Callback function called by Chainlink Oracle with the response
    function fulfill(
        bytes32 requestId,
        uint256 result
    ) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(requestId) {
        // Process the API response here
        emit APIResponse(result);
    }
}
```

The version I use for ChainlinkClient is v0.8, and Solidity runs in 0.8.16. I looked up the docs [here](https://docs.chain.link/any-api/api-reference#add) using the `req.add()` but somehow compiler doesnt detect `add`.

Any advice would greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the contract declaration, add `using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;` and that would fix the error.

```
contract FastAPI is ChainlinkClient {
    using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;

    // Chainlink variables
    address private oracle;
    bytes32 private jobId;
```

Comment: thanks! this helped! Why is that? I thought the Contract with extend of ChainlinkClient was enough..

Answer (score 0):

I think, add function needs 3 parameters, and you are passing only 2.
[image]

Consider reading the docs carefully and make sure to pass correct number of arguments.